# How often is database optimization NOT possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Currently I am working on a database that requires me to take raw data from a 3rd party and store it into a database. The problem is that the raw data is obviously not optimized, and the people who I'm building the database for, don't want any data entry involved when uploading the raw data into the database, they pretty much just want to upload the data and be done with it. Some of the raw data files have empty cells all over the place and many instances of duplicate names/numbers/entries. Is there a way to still optimize the data quickly and efficiently without too much data entry or reworking each time data is uploaded or is this an instant where optimization is impossible due to constrants? Does this happen a lot, or do I need to tell them their dreams of just uploading are not possible for long team success?

Comment: Looks like you need an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to optimize data and one way to optimize data in one use case may be horrible in another use case. There are tools that will tell you there are multiple values in columns that need to be optimized but there is no single advice which works in all cases.

without specific details, this is always good:

- With regards to empty entries, that should not be an issue
- With regards to duplicate data, it may be worth considering adding a one to many relationship
- One thing need to make sure is to put a key in any field you are going to search for, this will speed up a lot your queries no matter the dataset
- as far as changing the database schema... rare are the schemas that do not change over time.

My advice is think through your schema but do not try to over optimize things because you can not plan in advance what the exact usage will be. As long as it is working and there is no bottleneck, focus on other areas. If there is a bottleneck, then by all means, rewrite the affected part, making sure indices are present (consider composite indices in some cases). Consider avoiding unions when possible. and remember the KISS principle (Keep It Simple and Sweet).

Comment: I guess my issues is that raw data they get come in single files, and they want to just "upload" these files to the database without much/any modification to the original data. I could obviously take these data files and separate them out into various tables and create relationships, but this would require separating them out each time they want to upload those files, and I think thats what they are trying to avoid. Maybe you are right, I need to just keep it as simple as possible, and not worry about going to hard on the optimization.

Comment: it is many times a judgement call. Try to break down to a certain point your data. You may be able to use a few regex to automatically fill some of your columns. An alternative may be nosql which shines with non structured data but the way to query data (map/reduce) is very different from sql joins.